# Was Descent in to Avernus based on a prior adventure?

Tags: dnd-5e, baldurs-gate-descent-into-avernus

I recently discovered that:

> In the video game [Baldur's Gate: Siege of Dragonspear](http://www.siegeofdragonspear.com/), a portal to the Nine Hells is opened and a devil's army is unleashed on the Material Plane.

Is there any link to this game and [Baldur's Gate: Descent to Avernus](https://dnd.wizards.com/products/tabletop-games/rpg-products/baldursgate_descent), or is this basically just a coincidence?

Comment: Apologies if I hid too much behind the spoiler tag, but I was just worried that the connection would be obvious and possibly spoil the ending of the game for anyone that had not finished it yet.

Comment: Spoilers are fine...I'd rather people spoiler too many things than not enough things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### No.

> That aspect of the *Baldur's Gate: Siege of Dragonspear* video game plot ties back to the *Icewind Dale* video games.

> The powerful devil Belhifet, the final boss of *Siege of Dragonspear*, is also the final boss of *Icewind Dale*, and figures prominently in the plot of *Icewind Dale 2*.

I could find no connection between that aspect of the other game's plot and anything in *Baldur's Gate: Descent into Avernus.*